# A wordsearch c program assignment

Tags: c

EDIT: My new question is how can i put words in a random location on the grid, ive tried like below but just get a single random letter in the same spot. And also have i done the functions correctly as i feel that that may be the issue.

```html
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

char **createArray(); //function prototype
void printArray(char** array);
void insertHorizontally(char*word, char** array);
#define WIDTH 16
#define HEIGHT 16
char** myArray; //global array
void main()
{
 char words[4] = {'f','r','e','e'};
 myArray = createArray();
 insertHorizontally(words,myArray);
 printArray(myArray);
 
}
 //Creates a 2D array of WIDTH * HEIGHT and returns a pointer to it
char **createArray()
{
 int i,j;
 char **array = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char *) * WIDTH);
 for(i=0; i<WIDTH; i++)
 {
  array[i] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * HEIGHT);
 }
  for(i=0; i<WIDTH; i++)
  {
  for(j=0; j<HEIGHT; j++)
   {
    //words[i][j] = 65 + rand() % 25;
    array[i][j] = '_';
   }
  }
  return array;
}
void printArray(char** array)
{
 int i,j;
 array =myArray;
 for(i=0; i<WIDTH; i++)
  {
  for(j=0; j<HEIGHT; j++)
   {
   printf(" %c ", array[i][j]);
  }
  printf("\n");
 }
}
void insertHorizontally(char*word, char** array)
{
 array=&myArray;
 array=&rand();
 word = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * HEIGHT);
 int i,j,a;
 for(j = 0; j<HEIGHT; j++)
 {
  for(a=0;a<sizeof(word);a++) 
  {
   array[i][j] = *word;
  }
 }
 
}
```

Comment: Please read this article: [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and consider removing your question. We are not here to do your homework, but happy to help if you have a specific programming issue.

Comment: sorry i have changed it now, i just wanted to know how to input a random word into the grid

Comment: What happened to `insertHorizontally`? Most of the code is missing and what's there makes no sense.

Comment: its in the code snippet isnt it? I havent removed anything.

Comment: We see the same thing you see and the `insertHorizontally` function is incomplete. The function doesn't even have a closing brace.

Comment: Ask yourself what  you're doing with the `word` and `array` parameters that are passed into `insertHorizontally`. You're overwriting both of them with nonsense. You're setting `array` to point to the `rand` function and you're overwriting the address contained in `word`. You shouldn't be assigning anything to either of these parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
array=&myArray;//overwrite
array=&rand();//overwrite?, `&rand()` invalid
word = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * HEIGHT);//overwrite
sizeof(word)//pointer size, change to `char words[] = "free";...strlen(word)
```

write in a horizontal direction at random positions:

```
void insertHorizontally(char*word, char** array)
{
    int word_len = 4;
    int i = rand() % (HEIGHT-word_len+1);
    int j = rand() % WIDTH;
    int k;
    for(k=0;k < word_len;k++) {
        array[j][i+k] = word[k];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly, it seems so obvious now i see it

Comment: I think `HEIGHT` <--> `WIDTH`.

Comment: ye i noticed but i don't want to switch them until i finish the program in case i manage to botch things up